# Multifigure in 2-column pushed 2 pages forward

Tags: floats, subfloats

I've tried multiple solutions leaving me with no option but to ask the community. I have the following code:

```
\documentclass[10pt, final, journal, letterpaper, twocolumn]{IEEEtran}
%\documentclass[10pt,twocolumn]{article}

\usepackage[caption=false]{subfig}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{todonotes}

\usepackage[extendedchars]{grffile}


\begin{document}

\begin{figure*}[t]
\centering
\subfloat[1]{
    \missingfigure[figwidth=0.3\textwidth]{foo}
}
\subfloat[2]{
    \missingfigure[figwidth=0.3\textwidth]{foo}
}
\subfloat[3]{
    \missingfigure[figwidth=0.3\textwidth]{foo}
}
\caption{A figure with two subfigures}
\label{fig:size}
\end{figure*}


The earliest known appearance of the phrase is from The Boston Journal. In an article titled "Current Notes" in the February 10, 1885 morning edition, the phrase is mentioned as a good practice sentence for writing students: "A favorite copy set by writing teachers for their pupils is the following, because it contains every letter of the alphabet: 'A quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.'" A quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog. A quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog. A quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog. A quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog. Best believe A quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog. A quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog. A quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog. A quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog. A quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog. A quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog. A quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog. A quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.  A quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog. A quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog. A quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog. A quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.A quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog. A quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog. A quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog. A quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.  A quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog. A quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog. A quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog. A quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog. A quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog. A quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog. A quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog. A quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.  A quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog. A quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog. A quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog. A quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.

A quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog. A quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog. A quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog. A quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.  A quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog. A quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog. A quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog. A quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog. A quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog. A quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog. A quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog. A quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.  A quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog. A quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog. A quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog. A quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.

A quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog. A quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog. A quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog. A quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.  A quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog. A quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog. A quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog. A quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog. A quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog. A quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog. A quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog. A quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.  A quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog. A quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog. A quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog. A quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.
```

The problem seems to show up when using `IEEEtran.cls`, but I've never had this problem in the past. The resulting figures appears to be 2 pages away from where it is supposed to be and **right at the center of the page**. I have tried using the `[h]`, `[t]`, `[H]` options with `\figure` and I tried playing with `\topfraction` and `\bottomfraction`, but nothing is working. I also tried using `tabular` instead of `\subfloat`.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: welcome to tex.se! `figure*` always appear at the top of the next page from where is inserted (therefore placement options haven't any affect). since you not provide any information about image size and document layout, we can't help you further (images can be to big). please edit your question and provide small but complete document with dummy text and your images, which start with `\documentclass....` and end with `\end{document}`.

Comment: @Zarko Thank you. I have edited the post to give an example that reproduces the problem.

Comment: @any news? does answer help you?

Answer (score 1):

this is rather extended comment ...

as i mentioned in comment above, `figure*` always appear at the top of the next page from where it is inserted. if you like to have it on the bottom of the same page, than you need to use the `stfloats` package.

if you will have enough text in your article, than image will appear at top of the next page after its insertion. for example, with use of the standard `graphicx` package and its syntax, insertion in the first page it will appear on the top of the second page:

```
\documentclass[10pt, final, journal, letterpaper, twocolumn]{IEEEtran}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[caption=false]{subfig}
\usepackage{float}     
\usepackage{todonotes}

\usepackage[extendedchars]{grffile}
\usepackage{lipsum} % generate dummy text, don't use it in real document

\begin{document}
\lipsum

\textbf{Image is inserted here, but it will appear on the top of the next page if will be there also a some text.}

\begin{figure*}%[t]   % <-- image is inserted on the first page
                      %     but it will appear on the top of the second page
\centering
\subfloat[1]{
    \includegraphics[width=0.3\textwidth]{example-image-duck}
            }\hfill
\subfloat[2]{
    \includegraphics[width=0.3\textwidth]{example-image-duck}
            }\hfill
\subfloat[3]{
    \includegraphics[width=0.3\textwidth]{example-image-duck}
            }
\caption{A figure with three subfigures}
\label{fig:size}
\end{figure*}
\lipsum
\end{document}
```

i.e., you will obtain something like this:

[image]

and with your code for images:

```
\begin{figure*}
\centering
\subfloat[1]{
    \missingfigure[figwidth=0.3\textwidth]{foo}
}
\subfloat[2]{
    \missingfigure[figwidth=0.3\textwidth]{foo}
}
\subfloat[3]{
    \missingfigure[figwidth=0.3\textwidth]{foo}
}
\caption{A figure with two subfigures}
\label{fig:size}
\end{figure*}
```

the result is:

[image]

*conclusion:* with your document example it is not possible to reproduce your problem. of course, if you have text only on the first page, than the figure will appear at middle of the next page, but not two page after its insertion.